# IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to avoid push notifications error when previewing in the iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM Worklight 6.0.0 and testing on iOS 7 Simulator.

I have the following JavaScript error. It appears everytime I login.

```
Error while trying to retrieve device token from the mobile operating system.
  (anonymous function)           cordova.js:5312
  __log                        worklight.js:1292
  (anonymous function)         worklight.js:1377
  __updateTokenCallbackError    wlgap.ios.js:403
```

On the client side, my code is:

```
if (WL.Client.Push){

    WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe = function(){
        WL.Logger.debug("onReadyToSubscribe");

        if (isPushSubscribed() == false) {
            doSubscribe();
        }
    };  
}
if (WL.Client.Push){
        WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback(
                "myPush", 
                "PushAdapter", 
                "PushEventSource", 
                pushNotificationReceived);
}
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Please refer to the answer in the first question you opened: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433302/ibm-worklight-cannot-register-to-event-source-callback-with-an-existing-alias/19453532#19453532

Comment: Thanks, I solved the other issue, but this js error is still there on simulator. It's not very important since it does not appear on device.

I updated the question after resolving the other error

Comment: There is no push support in the iOS Simulator; you can only test on a device.

Comment: yes, I know, I wanted only to remove the js error. I think WL.Client.Push should be undefined on simulator, like it is in desktop browser.

Comment: With a bit of work you can detect if you're on the simulator, but I don't think its worth it. There is a global variable called 'device' that you can use to see if you're on the iphone simulator. Do a console.log(device) in your code and view the object to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Cordova's device.name](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.6.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.name) API method. You can also use [WL.Client.getEnvironment](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wl_client_getenvironment.html) to do the same, but for when previewing in the Worklight Console.

If you get "iPhone Simulator" (or "Preview" in the case Worklight Console), don't enter into those code blocks... do something else instead. Otherwise, continue into them.