# IBM Worklight - Cannot register to event source callback with an existing alias. The alias is already in use for event source

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using IBM Worklight 6.0.0 and testing on iOS 7 device.

I have the following js error:

```
Cannot register to event source callback with an existing alias: 'myPush'. The alias is already in use for event source 'PushEventSource'.
```

On device, when I login, logout then login again. (error appear the second time)

On the client side, my code is:

```
if (WL.Client.Push){
    WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe = function(){
        WL.Logger.debug("onReadyToSubscribe");
        WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback(
                "myPush", 
                "PushAdapter", 
                "PushEventSource", 
                pushNotificationReceived);
        if (isPushSubscribed() == false) {
            doSubscribe();
        }
    };  
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code?

Is it because I should call "WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback" only once?

Any other solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not allowed to register an alias more than once as the error message shows. The error isn't that harmful, since regardless of the error message you can still receive push notifications (you may want to test this to be sure).

If you want to avoid the error message you have two options:

1. Ensure that the call to WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback
   is called only once per app session, regardless of whether or not
   the user has logged out.
2. Make a call to WL.Client.Push.unsubscribe when the user logs out to
   clear the binding from the alias to the event source.

I'd suggest going with option 1. Push notification is tied to the device, not the user. Unless you plan on changing the event source alias for different users, there is no point in unsubscribing.