# Worklight Notification PUSH Unsubscribe user from eventSource

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I subscribe à user to the same eventSource with many alias. Is there any method to unsubscribe the user from this eventSource with all alias or i'm forced to unsubscribe one by one ???

Answer (score 0):

*This question is very not clear.
You need to edit your question with a better explanation and maybe even code snippets showing what exactly is it that you're doing there...*

Thoughts:

- Every eventSource can have 1 alias, so maybe what you meant to write is that you are subscribing several *users* to the same eventSource?
- Or did you mean that you are subscribing the same user to the same eventSource from multiple Devices?
- Or maybe you are in fact subscribing your user to different eventSources (each has its own alias)?

---

Either way, there is no API to iterate over all aliases and unsubscribe; you need to go over your subscriptions one-by-one and unsubscribe.

You could do this manually via the Worklight database > usersubscription table. There you will need to delete all the related entries, but that is not a recommended way to do it...

Possibly related question:

- [IBM Worklight - Cannot register to event source callback with an existing alias. The alias is already in use for event source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433302/ibm-worklight-cannot-register-to-event-source-callback-with-an-existing-alias)

Comment: Every eventSource can have 1 alias !! why ? I would like to subscribe devices to many eventSource but i don't have a list of possbile eventSources in advance for this reason i am using one eventSource and multiple alias because i can't add an eventSource dynamicly on my adapter. in adapter for sending push to specific alias i get all deviceSubcribtion for my eventSource and i check alias for sending or not my notification. In my app i check if the alias is subscribed befor do subscrib.